# Google Drive - Api V3 - CURL - Create Folders, Subfolder - Parends ID

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, filemaker

I´m using filemaker to save files via google drive API - CURL option. I want to save documents with this path:

```
Companies
          *Proyects
                -Purchase Orders
                     - Purchase Order 1 (Folder)
                             - File 1
                             - File 2
                             - ....
                     - Purchase Order 2
                     - .........
                - Invoices
                     - Invoice 1 (folder)
                            - File 1
                            - File s
                     - Invoice 2
                     - .........
```

I have already been able to use Drive API.
My access token can be used for the POST method.

I can create new folder in my Google Drive using a curl command.

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ### your access token ###' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name": "mb", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}' \
  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

This method will create a folder with the same name each time the script runs. But if I only want to save a new document inside "Purchase Order 1" folder I dont know how can I do.

Is there a way to do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I cannot understand about `a new document` of `if I only want to save a new document inside "Purchase Order 1" folder I dont know how can I do.`? Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Yes, I want to save a new document inside the folder.
But before I need to create the folder, so I need to know if the foldet exist or not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to check whether the folder is existing, "Files: list" of Drive API can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) When you want to create new Google Document to the specific folder, you can use `parents` in the request body. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but if I have the same name folder to diferents companies (For example, always there are a Prucharse 1 folder name).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `if I have the same name folder to diferents companies (For example, always there are a Prucharse 1 folder name).`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my English not is the best.
I have the same folder name in each company folder. So I need to look for the name only in this company.
It is so dificult to save one file in a specifict folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I have the same folder name in each company folder.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, really I only want to save a file in this path:
Proyects/Purchase Orders/Purchase Order 1/

I have "Purchase Order 1" in all Proyects folder.

How can I save my fale in this path? In synology I only have to name de rute.

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your replying, at Google Drive, the folders are managed by the folder IDs. So for example, when you want to put a file to "sample" folder, it is required to put it using the folder ID of "sample". If you have already known the folder ID, you can directly use it. If you have not known the folder ID, at that time, it is required to retrieve the folder ID from the folder structures. If this information was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Very useful, but which is the best option to find "ID folder" - I need to know the id folder of this strcuture: Proyects/Purchase Orders/Purchase Order 1/
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to retrieve the folder IDs from `Proyects/Purchase Orders/Purchase Order 1/`, the following flow can be considered. 1. The folder ID of `Proyects` can be retrieved by the method of "Files: list" in Drive API. 2. Folder ID of `Purchase Orders` under `Proyects` can be retrieved by the method of "Files: list" with the search query of `'### folder ID of Proyects ###' in parents`.

Comment: 3. Folder ID of `Purchase Order 1` under `Purchase Orders` can be retrieved by the method of "Files: list" with the search query of `'### folder ID of Purchase Orders ###' in parents`. But if this flow is not the direction you expect, I apologize.